# SubReport display data in multi-column with dynamic height crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, subreport

I want to create a sub report that displays data in multi-column and I want the height of the sub report is dynamic and not fixed with (CanGrow = Yes) is that possible ?
at the time, I got to create a report that displays the data in multi-column but the height is fixed (CanGrow = No), but i want that height of the sureport is dynamic

My problem if i check (vertical and across)[in section details of the subreport] in order to get multi-colomn and if CanGrow option of the subreport is checked i get only one column

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite confusing but I think you are looking for can Grow check box for Subreport. If it is true then right Click on sub report, go to **Format Subreport...** Under Common tab you will find **Can Grow** check box.
let me know if your requirement is something else.

Comment: My question is if there is a solution to create a dynamic subreport that displays data in multi-column (vertical and across) , because the only solution i found up to now is display a subreport with multi-column (vertical and across) when the height of a subreport is fixed

Comment: your subreport will grow in height automatically once you will check can grow check box on sub report.

Comment: the problem if i check (vertical and across) [section details of the subreport] in order to get multi-colomn and if CanGrow option of the subreport is checked i get only one column

Comment: Can grow check box will not increase the width of the column or subreport. You will have to manually increase the width of the subreport or column. Click on subreport and stretch it. Your column might have got hidden due to small width of subreport.

Answer (score 0):

To the extent I understand your question, Below is my answer.

When you create a report its height is fixed but as data is added to the report it increases but this is not the case with sub report.

For Sub report you need to actually mention `can grow` option to 0 to maintaint the report to extend as possible.

Now coming to your question create a sub report with can grow option to 0 and place it in another report and just use the report.

If your question is not this one let me know will try to answer.

Comment: I should create a sub report with can grow checked and place it in another report and just use the report, but why i can display a multi colomn (vertical and across ) in subreport, My question is it possible to display multi column (vertical and across) if the Can Grow option of subreport is checked?

Comment: Your comment is confusing.. refine it so that I can answer.

Comment: the problem if i check (vertical and across) in order to get multi-colomn and if CanGrow option of the subreport is checked i get only one column

Comment: What is the placement of the subreport in main report?

Comment: Stretch the sub report to the size of the main report, Now you can see all columns in the sub report

Answer (score 0):

Since you probably by now already have the "Can "Grow" prperty set, see that the width of the subreport report box is sufficient to hold two columns. As by default there will be margins in the main Report as well as subreport , so this might reduce the space available for the subreport to insert another column and it will move on to next page. Reduce the margins in the subreport and main report on left and right side and try increasing the width of the subreport box.